# Azure authentication - Allowed token audience value needs to be either URI or GUID format

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

After Authentication menu were updated in Azure I'm not able to set up an allowed audience api://app-id. In the "Authentication (Classic)" I was able to set up this type of allowed audience. Someone know how to configure it in this new authentication interface

[image: Azure function - Authentication]

[image]

Comment: Hi Felix, If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported this issue to Microsoft and they has been fixed, so, Now is possible set allowed audience with api://{app-id}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to see this document: https://www.eliostruyf.com/securing-azure-functions-existing-azure-ad-app/#allowed-token-audiences

`api://<client id>` is not a valid URI.

You could update the existing Application ID URI(`api://<client id>`) to `https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/xxx` and make sure to provide a unique URL.